# Get site list in Fieldset

Tags: magento2, extensions, adminhtml, adminform

```
`use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

...

class AccountSettintsGroup extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Fieldset
```

...

```
    try {
        $om = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $manager */
        $this->storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

`

Magento gives out blank page and does not create StoreManager object.

Comment: Well the code that creates the store manager object is commented that may be the reason ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism sorry about that - no . it is not exactly the reason , just I've copy pasted it here wrongly . This is not the reason in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$objManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->storeManager = $objManager -> create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
```

Instead of "**get**" you can use "**create**".